# Name Specific Accounts and Delete Specific accounts in Google Ads (formerly Google Adwords)

Tags: ads, google-adwords

I'm having my first experience with Google Ads (previously Google Adwords) and I'd like to know how I go about giving the accounts I set up actual names as opposed to the generic numbers you see when an account is created (see image attached).

This screenshot was taken of the drop down menu that appears when you click the account icon in the top right of the screen.

Also how do I delete one these accounts - for instance I'd like to delete the one that begins with the number 238?

Many thanks,

[image]